# How to make task bar launchers like the one that comes by default for Dolphin file explorer in KDE?

Tags: launcher, kde, dolphin

KDE comes with a launcher for dolphin by default, which when opened, the icon disappears and is replaced by the tab in the task manager. Once the window is closed the icon reappears.
I can't find a way to make such launchers for other apps.
The default launcher widget doesn't behave the same.